# how to enter a function to a file in c

Tags: c, file, io

I have this function in a code that im trying to enter to an I/O file and I cannot seem to do it.

```
void show_list(int whyeven[stuff], char *hatred[stuff])
{
  for (int g = 0; g < stuff - 1; g++)
  {
    if (whyeven[g] < 10 || whyeven[g] == 0)
    {
      printf("%s    -   %d   (*)  you should buy more of this stuff\n\n",hatred[g], whyeven[g]);
    }
    else if (whyeven[g] > 10)
    {
      printf("%s   -    %d\n\n", hatred[g], whyeven[g]);
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  show_list(moarstuff, items);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: We have no idea what it's supposed to do and what it is (and isn't) doing.  Please clarify.  Also, provide a [mcve]

Comment: Why test for `whyeven[g] < 10 || whyeven[g] == 0`? The second is included in the first.  Also, you're testing for `whyeven[g] < 10` and later for `whyeven[g] > 10`.  What about when `whyeven[g] == 10`?

Comment: One more thing, you're not sending `stuff` to your function, though you think you are.

Answer (score 1):

`printf()` prints to `stdout`. You need to `fopen()` that file and then use `fprintf()` with the returned from `fopen()` `FILE*` pointer as the first argument.

```
/* Open the file for writing */
FILE* fp = fopen("filename.txt", "w");
/* Check for errors */
if (fp == NULL)
{
    /* Notify the user of the respective error and exit */
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
/* Write to the file */
fprintf(fp, "Hello!\n");
/* Close the file */
fclose(fp);
```

Note: Your question was quite unclear and this answer is based on what I could understand out of it.

Comment: Generic `this is how you do buffered file I/O` is clearly a WAG at some solution to some problem somewhere - but connection to the OP is less than tenuous.

Comment: I know. I'd rather prefer a more specific question.